# downloading and using phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to back up my website for the first time.  I don't really understand much on the wordpress support page for this as I'm not a particularly techy person! I have tried to download phpmyadmin to back up that way but just seem to get a folder full of text files.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to use it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

a php program is a folder full of "text files"

step 1:
you have to create a folder in your server then put all the files of phpmyadmin

Then you can access to program by www.yourpage.com/yourfoldercreate

step 2:
there is a file call config.sample.inc.php you have to copy to config.inc.php ,this file is the configuration of the program, the sample is ok

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress site consists of "source files" -- the PHP files that make WordPress work (which sometimes include customizations such as plugins or themes) and entries in a database (probably MySQL). The database portion is what you're trying to back up through phpMyAdmin. In my case, I generally back up the WordPress source files also, in order to make restoration quick and easy.

You wrote "I have tried to download phpmyadmin...but just seem to get a folder full of text files" so I suspect what is actually happening is that you downloaded the phpMyAdmin source files (the PHP files that are designed to run through your web site) and are looking at that folder. What you need to do instead is upload that folder to your website (I would use a non-standard name for the folder, as many servers see attack attemps on variations of wwexample.com/phpmyadmin). Anyway, as Troncador says, once you upload that to your web host you can access it through your web page and continue with the download steps (select your database from the left hand navigation menu, then look for the Export tab).